# Altering excel cell font aspects when I click on the cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a spreadsheet which records information points in a standard way.

The design is thus:
A2 is "Pain"

- The cell should default to a grey text color (normal background) (color index 16)
- upon a left mouse click, the text color should turn black (color index 1)
- upon the next left mouse click the text should become struck through and slightly different color (font.strikethrough = true) (color index 56)
- upon the next left mouse click, the text should return to its original state (color index 16, no strikethrough)

I'm trying this code but it doesn't appear to be working.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  With Target
.Font.Name = "Calibri"
.Font.Size = 11
  If .Address = Range("A2").Address Then
Select Case .Font.ColorIndex
  Case 16
    .Font.ColorIndex = 1
  Case 1
    .Font.ColorIndex = 56
    .Font.Strikethrough = True
  Case 56
    .Font.ColorIndex = 16
    .Font.Strikethrough = False
  Case Else
    .Font.ColorIndex = 16
End Select
  End If
  End With
  Range("A3").Select
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Please help me to figure out how to achieve this aim.

THANKS!

Comment: what's not working, works fine for me.

Comment: Have you checked that Application.EnableEvents is `True`?  If you errored out of a different code block it may currently be `False`.  (Also, `If Not Intersect(Target,Me.Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then` may be preferable to the address check, especially if you need to do the same thing to several cells in a Range)

Comment: Perhaps you put your code in the wrong module? Is it in the Sheet*n* module?